# Count Row / Entry in table after each new user in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in database, table structure below

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | M001 |
| 2 | M002 |
| 3 | M003 |
| 4 | M004 |

i want to count row/entry after each new user, means after user_id M001 there 3 entries , after M002 there 2 entry , after M004 there 1 entry and so on

need some PHP function to count entries after each user .

expected result:

> user_id > entry after that user

like this

```
M001 > 3
M002 > 2
M003 > 1
M004 > 0
```

i dont know how to do that.

Comment: This only works if you add a `DATETIME` column with `created_at`.

Comment: @DanielW. Not necessarily. It should work with `id` too if it's a a primary key.

Comment: @HonzaOne id primary key / auto increment is not reliable. Someone could add `M005` with id `123` and `M006` with id `99`. Even less deterministic when you have a replica set.

Comment: i think no need of date time , i just need entry count after each user in table , this is a table where entry will be once per user that M002 may come in first M003 may come in 4th position no matter, just need count how many entry after each user .

Comment: @DanielW. You're right. But doesn't it technically apply to the `created_at` column as well? I think it can work only if you have control over the table structure and what is inserted to it. But I totally agree that adding the `DATETIME` column seems like the most logical solution.

Comment: @HonzaOne It's not about control, but about semantics. A primary / auto increment key has no semantical affiliation with "chronology". It's not a time based value. Its (semantic) purpose is to "identify" a distinct row. In a small project, there is (almost) no difference, but when you handle millions of rows over multiple servers, it becomes a big deal.

Comment: @TauisifAhmad I'm not sure I understand the logic. What exactly is it that makes one user come after another? Does M003 always go after M002 even if M003 was added in the table earlier? Then it would mean that you want to sort the `user_id` column alphabetically, I guess.

Comment: @DanielW. I agree. You're right. However, it seems that this table might follow a completely different logic than what we were discussing.

Comment: @HonzaOne there some condition for that i created a table and inserting user_id to that table, and once a user_id inserted it wont repeated so there will be a list of user_id in table so that if i see in table we can see how many user_id means if there total 10 entry and we see in table we will find 9 entry for after first entry , 8 entry after second entry in table and so on

Comment: @TauisifAhmad I understand that. But the main question still stands. You have to define what this "after" means. Can M001 be after M002 if it was inserted later or is it always before because it stands alphabetically before M002?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with a reverse sort on `id` and then subtract `1`:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (order by id desc) - 1) as entries_after
from t;
```

You can also do this with a correlated subquery.  This is not particularly efficient, but it is fine for small data sets:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.id > t.id) as entries_after
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked , please update the answer as it giving error on alias after adding brackets to (row_number() over (order by id desc) - 1) it worked

Comment: on local host working fine but on server getting error  
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'over (order by id desc) - 1) as entries_after from non_working_list LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Host Server version: 5.7.23-23 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 23, Revision 500fcf5

Comment: @TauisifAhmad . . . This requires MySQL 8+, which was released three and a half years ago.

Comment: any alternative? because my hosting have lower version so , help please

Comment: in second query you are using t and t2 but i have only one table

Comment: @TauisifAhmad . . . One table.  Referenced twice.  Hence two different aliases.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider that tables usually don't have default order. So you should define what exactly "after" means. If it means that the user was added later, you may add a datetime column with time of the insert and find rows with later insert date.

If `id` is a primary key, it will always be higher for newly added rows. So you can use that in your advantage and simply count rows with higher `id`.

So you can first find `id` of the `user_id` row like

`SELECT id FROM table WHERE user_id = 'M001'`

and then find number of rows with higher `id` than the one found with the previous query like this

`SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE id > 1`